# OSX Apache Virtualhost returns only default page

Tags: macos, apache, virtualhost

I have a problem using the build-in apache webserver under ElCapitan.

I want to set up my Sites-Directory in my users-directory. This works fine by adding a user config and and so on. So my localhost/~Fabian gives me the content of /User/Fabian/Sites/index.php.

Now I am trying to set up virtual hosts in this directory, e.g. /User/Fabian/Sites/Projekte/testsite.me/public.

So I activated the virtualhost module and included it in my httpd.conf. After this, I set up a virtualhost in the httpd-vhost.conf:

```
</VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin xyz@blubber.de
    DocumentRoot "/Users/Fabian/Sites/Projekte/testsite.me/public"
    ServerName testsite.me
    ErrorLog "/Users/Fabian/Sites/Logs/testsite-error_log"
    CustomLog "/Users/Fabian/Sites/Logs/testsite-custom_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

I also added the ServerAlias to my hosts file

```
127.0.0.1    testsite.me
```

Trying to open http://testsite.me shows me the default "It works"-page.

Running `apachectl configtest` gives me an syntax error:

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 499 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 74 of /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf: </VirtualHost without matching <VirtualHost section
```

Line 499 in httpd.conf looks like this:

```
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Line 74ff of httpd-vhosts.conf contain the virtualhost I defined above.

Any idea how to solve this problem? What is a VirtualHost section?

Thank you!

Comment: The [topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) at Stack Overflow is programming and this question seems to have very little to do with that. I think you'd get better, and more, responses in a more suitable Stack Exchange site like [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com), [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) or [Super User](http://superuser.com).

Answer (score 0):

You start your vhost definition with `</VirtualHost *:80>`
That should be `<VirtualHost *:80>` without the slash.
Although the apache config files are not xml, the Syntax for starting and ending sections are the same; so you start with `<tag>` and end with `</tag>`.